# How to fetch textbox value in radio button value in php

Tags: php, html

I have 3 radio buttons in my form. 2 of them have static values and the 3rd one has a radio button that should have the same value as the number entered in the textbox. I am able to fetch the first 2 radio buttons values by using $_POST method on next page but for the 3rd radio button, the value is null. Please help me get the textbox value for the 3rd radio button. The code is :

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="500000" checked="checked" />Purchase More than 5 Lakhs

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2000000" />Purchase More than 20 Lakhs

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" />Purchase More than : <input type="text" name="radio" />
```

Comment: The `name` attribute should be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve this using PHP, try this approach:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="500000" checked="checked" />Purchase More than 5 Lakhs
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2000000" />Purchase More than 20 Lakhs
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" />Purchase More than : <input type="text" name="user_entered" />
```

In your PHP file:

```
$result = $_POST['radio']?$_POST['radio']:$_POST['user_entered'];
```

This means: if `radio` is set, use `radio` value; else use the `user_entered` value.

Of course, you should further check if `user_entered` contains a valid value, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much Andre. The solution is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs should have different names. Call your type="text" input something different from radio and then you should be able to do  $_POST["newName"]